# How open a folder dialog in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

What should I do to call "open folder dialog" in JavaScript??
i have a image.

[image](http://v2.freep.cn/110_3tb_1402070038593ecs512293.jpg)

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 0):

Linking to local resources is disabled in modern browsers for security concerns.

Comment: you can access them with user permission, IE. they select the file for a file input.

Comment: can I open a directory? now I know how open file